# Data Studio on top of BigQuery Table, Filter breaking data connection

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I'm here with an issue about some filters on a DataStudio plugged on a single table in Bigquery.

It's a retail table, so I have product ids and some level categories, with a metric.

I did use filters on different level categories, it works fine. But when i do filter on product id, i do have a connection break with my data source.

That's the first issue.

[image: Connection error after product id filter]

Even before I do search in the filter for a product id, the filter box does not show all product ids matching the template I did give it (before accepting the filter, just the box display).

Comment: In the BQ console check query History for all users and see the generated wrong syntax. That's a clue to get you help into a good direction.

Comment: Thank you, nice clue. I should have check it before, but the failed queries logs looks not in real time at all. Is it batched or something like that?
Moreover all cols are anonymized, so it can be tricky to read^^
Last point when I try failed queries in my history from the dashboard, it runs fine :s

Comment: Another point, my failed filters are on product ids using "only" feature from filter. But my query runs with "not in" where it should be "in". But once again when i rerun the given query it runs fine in BQ.

Comment: The query history should be realtime. You can turn on the dat access auditlog, and dig for a SQL that will return you the executed query as well.

Comment: New web UI diff i guess, checked with old one, it is real time.

Answer (score 1):

Issue fixed from logs.

Thank you for your help.

This issue was about applying filter e.g. "IN" operator to a numeric field. I did cast in studio data source connector. But it looks like the cast did not follow within the filter connector. Casting within my BQ table did fix the issue.

But the filter box still does not match my given pattern, meaning some of my product ids cannot be filtered by. Is it because data studio filter feature cannot index 250k+ values?

Edit : 10k values in the filter component from here : https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144?visit_id=637072563886027802-222108669&rd=1

Just change the "style" of the component and it can index all of my results :)

[image: Change Filter Style]